# How can I close a primefaces panel through JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I have some fields where I have panels. Every time that field is loaded I want show a closed panel. For that I want to close those panels through JavaScript method. I cant use widgetVar because those panels are auto-generated.

```
        <p:dataTable>
           <p:column>...</p:column>
           <p:column>...</p:column>
           <p:column>...</p:column>
           <p:column><p:rowToggler/></p:column>
           <p:rowExpansion>
               .....
               .....
               <p:panel toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="1000" closeSpeed="500"
                collapsed="true">
                  .....
                  .....
                  .....
               </p:panel>

           </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Suppose I have expanded my first row and expanded my panel, then I close my first row. After that if I open my any other row I am getting panel as expanded(toggled).

After expanding any row I should get my panel closed(collapsed).

Comment: Can you post what you already have?

Comment: @SethMcClaine Thanks for your quick response. Please check I have updated my ques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a different widgetVar for each row like this:

```
<p:panel widgetVar="panel_#{row_identifier}" ...>
```

Then you can call it through JavaScript. For example, if your row identifier is 2:

```
panel_2.collapse();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I also try collapse method with css class selector. Ex ('.myPanel').collapse() . This is the case when I would like to collapse all panels in the page.

Comment: I don't believe so. I've searched extensively but never found a way to convert from a JQuery object into a PrimeFaces object. However, I freely admit I could be wrong.

Comment: @patstuart how to call this from javascript? like what is the event ? i think panel does not support any javascript method calling. Please advise(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812416/on-close-event-primefaces-is-not-working-on-panel)

Comment: @SAR I haven't worked in Primefaces for 6 years. My knowledge is gone and would be hopelessly out of date even if it weren't. :)

Comment: @patstuart, great of you for responding. Thank you very much and i was able to solve it, toggle is the even which gets fired always and there is status (VISIBLE and HIDDEN) handled it with the help of status.